pyspark Exception in collect and take, first actions
I'm new to pyspark, i'm taking a beginner friendly course in that the first step was to import data and split based on delimeter comma (","), after splitting the data when i try to execute collect or  take actions its throwing an error, please assist.
import os
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(master='local',appName='test_advent')
print(sc)
path = r'C:\Users\Documents\spark\Adventure\Adventure_RDD'
file = os.path.join(path,'Employee.csv')
Employee_RDD = sc.textFile(file)
Employee_RDD = Employee_RDD.map(lambda x:x.split(','))
print(Employee_RDD.collect())

Error is as below:
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 print(Employee_RDD.collect())

File ~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:2836, in RDD.take(self, num)
   2833         taken += 1
   2835 p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 2836 res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   2838 items += res
   2839 partsScanned += numPartsToTry

File ~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:2319, in SparkContext.runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   2317 mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
   2318 assert self._jvm is not None
-> 2319 sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   2320 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))

File ~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6) (INNF7WQTN3.zone1.scb.net executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:170)
    
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    .. 17 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified



Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

There's an issue with running Python scripts within Spark. The error indicates that Spark cannot find the Python executable (python3). This could be due to a misconfiguration in your Spark setup.
Make sure that you can execute python3 on command line before starting the main Spark application.
